# cannot add showcase library to my android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to add the ShowCaseView project from gitHub to my android project in eclipse.
I know this question was asked before, and I found some answers, but nothing worked for me.
I downloaded the project from : [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

I tryied copying the peject to my work space, importing it, checking "is library" and than add the library into my project.
everything goes well, it looks like it suppose to work (ther is a green check mark near the library) but I can't use the project.

when I'm trying to use the code it doesn't recognize it.
I even closed and restarted Eclipse, tried to clean the project, tried to copy the jar file.. nothing worked!

I would appriciate if someone can solve this problem to me!
thanks!

Comment: is your library project and working project located on same location ? if not then put on same folder and then test as well.

Comment: Yes. Both are in the same folder..